# sql performance by complex queries

Tags: sql-server

I have a table like below:

```
CREATE TABLE MetalTemprature(
    idMetalTemprature int
    rawTime bigint NOT NULL,
    metal nchar(7) NOT NULL,
    color nchar(5) NOT NULL,
    Temp float NOT NULL)
```

and blow index:

```
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    idMetalTemprature ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON PRIMARY
) ON PRIMARY

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX NonClusteredIndex1112 ON MetalTemprature
(
    rawTime DESC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON PRIMARY
```

when I run this query take 0 sec to do that:

```
SELECT  count(*)
  FROM MetalTemprature
  where rawTime < 4449449575 and  rawTime > (4449449575 -10000000) and  metal = 'iron';
```

but when i put this query under other select like below

```
SELECT 
    SELECT  count(*)
          FROM MetalTemprature
          where rawTime < other.rawTime and  rawTime > (other.rawTime -10000000) and  metal = 'iron';
from other_table_only_one_row as other;
```

this take about 60 sec (when that other.rawTime is only 4449449575 and result of both queries is same)why?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
from other_table_only_one_row as other, (SELECT  count(*)
          FROM MetalTemprature
          where rawTime < other.rawTime and  rawTime > (other.rawTime -10000000) and  metal = 'iron') as cnt
```

Place it into `FROM` section to execute just once

Comment: Thnaks but when I try it but i got error Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 10
The multi-part identifier "other.rawTime" could not be bound.